# How to read file having different line ending in C++

Tags: c++, file-handling, ifstream, getline, line-endings

I have two files "linuxUTF8.srt" and "macANSI.srt". I am reading these files using getline().
as macANSI.srt has '\r' as line ending I am reading the whole file rather than a single line.
I know I have to pass '\r' as delimiter but how do I know what type of line ending character I am dealing with.

Comment: You do not know and have to come up with detecting/heuristics. Either read the whole file or block-wise. As those are text files they are probably not too big. Decide whether to read files in binary or text mode.

Comment: I would suggest simply writing your own getline() that handles all 3 common line break formats equally: bare-CR, bare-LF, and CRLF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sebastian said, we will need to read the block and then find out the appropriate line-ending.
So, we will need to open the file in binary mode and read the last characters.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void SetLineEnding(char *filename, std::string &newline, char &delimiter)
{
    std::string str;
    std::ifstream chk(filename,std::ios::binary);
    if(getline(chk, str))
    {
        if(str.size() && str[str.size()-1] == '\r') 
        {
            //It can be either \r or \r\n
            if(getline(chk, str))
            {
                delimiter = '\n';
                newline = "\\r\\n";
            }
            else
            {
                delimiter = '\r';
                newline = "\\r";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            delimiter = '\n';
            newline = "\\n";
        }
    }
}
int32_t main()
{
    
    string newLine;
    string delimiter;
    char filename[256];
    in>>filename;
    SetLineEnding(filename,newLine,delimiter);
    std::ifstream inp(filename,ios::in);
    if(!inp.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"File not opened"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    //getline() function with delimiter
    string str;
    getline(inp,str,delimiter);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Now you can pass delimiter to getline() and you will be able to read according to line-ending.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning me. Good approach! But what about files, which do not end with a new line [of any kind]?

Comment: What if a file has line endings mixed? For example, a user of a Linux system edited a network-shared Windows file and now you have both CRLF and LF-only terminated lines.

Comment: @CiaPan Normally in those cases the last editor rewrites all line endings. If not, you could also first replace all CRLF with LF and then interpret as Unix line endings. Macintosh used CR only, which makes supporting a mix of all three schemes a bit too involved. (Is CRLF one Windows line ending or a mix of Mac + Unix, so two line endings?)